# C# decrypt AES from byte[] not complete input data

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to decrypt a byte[] the length of 30601 with the following method

```
public static byte[] DecryptObject(byte[] recObj, byte[] aesKey, byte[] aesIV) {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create()) {
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Key = aesKey;
            aes.IV = aesIV;

            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV)) {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                    cs.Write(recObj, 0, recObj.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have confirmed the key and iv is the same in which I used to encrypt with, but its throwing the error on cs.FlushFinalBlock(); with error

System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The input data is not a complete block.'

I have tried other methods to get this resolved but they are not working.

I am using this to encrypt

```
public static byte[] EncryptAes(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
        using (var aes = Aes.Create()) {
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                    cs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your input data was not correctly padded most likely, or you lost some of it / gained some extra bytes. The input data length needs to be a multiple of the block size, so check that first

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] by providing sample input data

Comment: What happens if the data length is not a multiple? 30601/128 = 239.07

Comment: @David, You get the error you're getting. Encrypting with a padding scheme should always produce output in full blocks. Check `ms.ToArray().Length`. It should be a multiple of 16, definitely not 30601.

Comment: @glenebob the length is 8576

Comment: @David, you'll need to figure out how 22,025 extra bytes got into the mix...